# IMPRIMIR DATOS EN UN ARREGLO BIDIMIENSIONAL

Tags: java, array

Hola muchachos estoy haciendo este programa en el que tengo que pedirle al usuario datos sobre 5 estudiantes el tema es que me piden que en la segunda opcion del menu imprima los datos que me dio el usuario usando una matriz bidimiensional en el siguiente orden:

sexo1  edad1  direccion1  appelido1  nombre1  cedula1  estudiante1

sexo2  edad2  direccion2  appelido2  nombre2  cedula2  estudiante2

sexo3  edad3  direccion3  appelido3  nombre3  cedula3  estudiante3

sexo4  edad4  direccion4  appelido4  nombre4  cedula4  estudiante4

sexo5  edad5  direccion5  appelido5  nombre5  cedula5  estudiante5

Espero que me puedan ayudar la verdad nose que hacer aqui esta lo que llevo:

```
package ejemplosparcial;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Ejemplosparcial {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int menuprogramainterno;
        int menuprograma;
        Double cedula1 = null, cedula2 = null,cedula3 = null,cedula4 = null,cedula5 = null;
        Double edad1 = null, edad2 = null, edad3 = null, edad4 = null, edad5 = null;

        String  nombre1 = null, apellido1 = null, direccion1 = null, sexo1 = null;
        String  nombre2 = null, apellido2 = null, direccion2 = null, sexo2 = null;
        String  nombre3 = null, apellido3 = null, direccion3 = null, sexo3 = null;
        String  nombre4 = null, apellido4 = null, direccion4 = null, sexo4 = null;
        String  nombre5 = null, apellido5 = null, direccion5 = null, sexo5 = null;

        String est1 = null, est2 = null, est3 = null, est4 = null, est5;

        Double promediocedula;
        int sw = 0;



        do {      
       menuprograma =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
               "Menu\n1 . Presione 1 para ingresar por primera vez o modificar la información existente de los 5 estudiantes. \n"
               + "2 . Presione 2 para mostrar lista de estudiantes con sus respectivos datos. \n3 . Presione 3 para Mostrar el promedio de las cedulas. "
               + "\n4 . Presione 4 para Modificar datos. \n5 . Presione 5 para Mostrar al estudiante mayor. \n6 . Presione 6 para mostrar al estudiante menor. "
               + "\n7 . Presione 7 para salir del programa.  ")); 

       switch(menuprograma){

           case 1:
               sw=2;
               int swi = 0;
                do {      
       menuprogramainterno =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Menu\n1 . Digite 1 para ingresar los datos del primer estudiante. \n"
               + "2 . Digite 2 para ingresar los datos del segundo estudiante. \n3 . Digite 3 para ingresar los datos del tercer estudiante. "
               + "\n4 . Digite 4 para ingresar los datos del cuarto estudiante. \n5 . Digite 5 para ingresar los datos del quinto estudiante. "
               + "\n6 . Digite 6 para volver al menu principal.  ")); 

       switch(menuprogramainterno){

           case 1:
                swi =2;
               cedula1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su cedula porfavor")); 
               nombre1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su nombre porfavor"); 
               apellido1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su apellido porfavor"); 
               direccion1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su dirección porfavor"); 
               edad1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su edad porfavor")); 
               sexo1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su sexo porfavor"); 


               break;

           case 2: 

               swi =2;

               cedula2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su cedula porfavor")); 
               nombre2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su nombre porfavor"); 
               apellido2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su apellido porfavor"); 
               direccion2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su dirección porfavor"); 
               edad2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su edad porfavor")); 
               sexo2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su sexo porfavor"); 

               break;

           case 3:

               swi =2;

               cedula3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su cedula porfavor")); 
               nombre3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su nombre porfavor"); 
               apellido3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su apellido porfavor"); 
               direccion3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su dirección porfavor"); 
               edad3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su edad porfavor")); 
               sexo3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su sexo porfavor"); 

               break;

            case 4:
                 swi =2;

               cedula4 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su cedula porfavor")); 
               nombre4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su nombre porfavor"); 
               apellido4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su apellido porfavor"); 
               direccion4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su dirección porfavor"); 
               edad4 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su edad porfavor")); 
               sexo4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su sexo porfavor"); 

               break;

            case 5:
                 swi =2;

               cedula5 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su cedula porfavor")); 
               nombre5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su nombre porfavor"); 
               apellido5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su apellido porfavor"); 
               direccion5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su dirección porfavor"); 
               edad5 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su edad porfavor")); 
               sexo5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su sexo porfavor"); 

               break;

           case 6:
             swi =0;


           break;

       }   

    } while (swi != 0);



               break;

           case 2: 

                sw=2;


               break;

           case 3:

                sw=2;
               // Promedio de cedulas

                  promediocedula = (cedula1 + cedula2+cedula3+cedula4+cedula5)/5;

                     //System.out.println("El promedio de las cedulas es"+promediocedula);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El promedio de las cedulas es"+promediocedula);



               break;

            case 4:
              sw=2;


               break;

            case 5:
                //Caso para descubrir el estudiante mayor.

               sw=2;

               if( (edad1>=edad2) &&  (edad1>=edad3) && (edad1>=edad4) &&  (edad1>=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante mayor es "+nombre1);
               }   

               else if( (edad2>=edad1) &&  (edad2>=edad3) && (edad2>=edad4) &&  (edad2>=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante mayor es "+nombre2);
               }  

               else if( (edad3>=edad1) &&  (edad3>=edad2) && (edad3>=edad4) &&  (edad3>=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante mayor es "+nombre3);
               }  

               else if( (edad4>=edad1) &&  (edad4>=edad3) && (edad4>=edad2) &&  (edad4>=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante mayor es "+nombre4);
               }  

               else if( (edad5>=edad1) &&  (edad5>=edad3) && (edad5>=edad4) &&  (edad5>=edad2) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante mayor es "+nombre5);
               }  

               else if( (edad2==edad1) &&  (edad2==edad3) && (edad2==edad4) &&  (edad2==edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Todos los estudiantes tienen la misma edad!!! ");
               }  


               break;

           case 6:
               //Caso para descubrir al estudiante menor.

           sw = 2;

                          if( (edad1<=edad2) &&  (edad1<=edad3) && (edad1<=edad4) &&  (edad1<=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante menor es "+nombre1);
               }   

               else if( (edad2<=edad1) &&  (edad2<=edad3) && (edad2<=edad4) &&  (edad2<=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante menor es "+nombre2);
               }  

               else if( (edad3<=edad1) &&  (edad3<=edad2) && (edad3<=edad4) &&  (edad3<=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante menor es "+nombre3);
               }  

               else if( (edad4<=edad1) &&  (edad4<=edad3) && (edad4<=edad2) &&  (edad4<=edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante menor es "+nombre4);
               }  

               else if( (edad5<=edad1) &&  (edad5<=edad3) && (edad5<=edad4) &&  (edad5<=edad2) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El estudiante menor es "+nombre5);
               }  

               else if( (edad2==edad1) &&  (edad2==edad3) && (edad2==edad4) &&  (edad2==edad5) )  {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Todos los estudiantes tienen la misma edad!!! ");
               }  


           break;

           case 7:
               // Salir del programa.
              sw=0;


           break;

       }   

    } while (sw != 0);

    }

}
```

Comment: No estás trabajando sobre javascript, por favor, quítalo de la lista de etiquetas.

Comment: Disculpen la calidad de mi codigo es que aun soy un poco principio en el mundo de la programación.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, te recomiendo que veas algo de cómo declarar matrices en Java y cómo imprimirlas, te ayudaría para esas cosas, si no lo puedes hacer, entonces tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
System.out.println(sexo1+" "+edad1+" "+direccion1+" "+appelido1+" "+nombre1+" "+cedula1+" "+estudiante1);
```

Y así hasta:

```
System.out.println(sexo5+" "+edad5+" "+direccion5+" "+appelido5+" "+nombre5+" "+cedula5+" "+estudiante5+"\n");
```

Para imprimir cada valor de las distintas variables en forma de una matriz, obviamente cada línea del `System.out.println` tendría que estar declarada debajo de la otra.

Y! En el caso de que puedas declarar matrices y trabajar sobre ellas, te dejo [este enlace](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/12/matriz-en-java.html) para que veas un ejemplo que te servirá.

**No pongo la respuesta usando matrices también porque no sé si puedes hacerlo.**